# Periodic group with bound on order of finite subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory

I have asked the same question previously on stackexchange without any answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923638/periodic-group-with-bounded-subgroups):

I am looking for infinite periodic groups $G$ (by periodic I mean that every element has finite order), whose finite subgroups are not arbitrarily large. So there is a constant $M$ such that for any finite subgroup $H$ of $G$ one has $|H| \leq M$.

A class of groups that satisfy these requirements are the Tarski monster groups. Here one can take $M = p$ for some prime $p$.

Are there any other notable examples or classes of examples?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_problem gives information. Yes there are such groups. None has an easily understood structure. Take any even integer $n=512 k \gt 2^{48}$ and $m \ge 2$ generators $x_1,\cdots,x_m$ with the relations $w^m=1$ for every possible finite word. This does define some group and it is infinite. Tarski Monster groups are know to exist for any prime $p \gt 10^{75}.$

Comment: It is known that finitely generated periodic finitely generated dimensional complex linear groups are finite, which is one reason to expect that the groups asked about will not be straightforward.

Comment: For the Burnside groups of even exponent, there are arbitrarily large finite subgroups: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869396969410

Comment: I believe for odd exponent free Burnside groups, sufficiently large, all finite subgroups are cyclic.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: At least in the mentioned paper by Ian Agol they additionally assume that the finite subgroup is also abelian (first paragraph of the introduction).

Comment: I believe Adjan proved in the odd case all finite subgroups are cyclic. It should be in his book.

Comment: In the book "The Burnside Problem and Identities in Groups" by Adjan I could only find Theorem 3.3 (on page 261), which states:
"Every commutative subgroup of $B(m,n)$ is cyclic of order dividing $n$, for odd $n \geq 665$."